# Expire cache fragment not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I'm trying to cache a side_bar. Into it, there is two list of groups (1: favorite groups, 2: others_groups)

My caching aproach:

1.caching the two lists of groups into my model User

```
 def cached_groups
    Rails.cache.fetch([self, "groups"]) {groups.to_a}
  end

  def cached_favgroups
    Rails.cache.fetch([self, "fav_groups"]) {fav_groups.to_a}
  end
```

2.caching the entire list and below each of the group

```
  <% cache 'cache_all_groups_fav' do %>
    <% current_user.cached_favgroups.each do |group| %>
      <% cache group do %>
        <%= render 'groups/group', group: group %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <% cache 'cache_all_groups' do %>
    <% current_user.cached_groups.each do |group| %>
      <% cache group do %>
        <%= render 'groups/group', group: group %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

3.Expire the cache into my Groups/Controller

```
def favorit
  FavoritGroup.where(group_id: @group.id).where(user_id: current_user.id).first_or_create
  Group.where(group_id: @group.id).where(user_id: current_user.id).delete_all
  expire_fragment('cache_all_groups_fav')
  expire_fragment('cache_all_groups')
  expire_fragment('cached_favgroups')
  expire_fragment('cached_groups')
  expire_fragment('group')
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_back }
    format.js { render 'groups/js/favorit' }
  end 
end 

def unfavorit
  FavoritGroup.where(group_id: @group.id).where(user_id: current_user.id).delete_all
  Group.where(group_id: @group.id).where(user_id: current_user.id).first_or_create
  expire_fragment('cache_all_groups_fav')
  expire_fragment('cache_all_groups')
  expire_fragment('cached_favgroups')
  expire_fragment('cached_groups')
  expire_fragment('group')
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_back }
    format.js { render 'groups/js/unfavorit' }
  end
end
```

Note : To do that, I'm store_cache 'dally' Ruby2.4 (Rails 5.1.4)

> Problem :  The expire_fragment method is not working

Do you have any idea of what problem can append here ?

Do you do the same for you cache strategy ?

Answer (score 1):

You should really be doing this caching in the front-end, with [russian doll caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#russian-doll-caching).

The cache will expire automatically when any of your group records are updated.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Daniel, I'm on it !